# Why have I to use session_start() to make session persist in Laravel 5.7.28

Tags: php, laravel, session, routes, middleware

I am trying to create a session in PagesController > designQuote function. The Laravel call to session works but the session does not persist. Here is the code.

```
Session::push('design_quote_uploads.files', ["Hello"]);
print_r(Session::all());
```

This works first time but when I comment out the first line *design_quote_uploads* does not exist in the session vars in the next page load.

The config/Session.php settings is

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

After reading doc and another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615318/laravel-5-2-session-not-persisting) I checked the Routes and Middleware and it looks like this:

In the web.php the call is:

```
Route::any('design-quote', 'PageController@designQuote');
```

The middlewareGroups in Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

If I place `session_start();` at the top of designQuote method the session persists. Do I have to keep it there?

**Edit**: (I swear) Placing `session_start()` worked yesterday but it is not working today :(

Also the session file at `storage/framework/sessions` is updated fine every time. I.e. It has data when it is written and misses data when I refresh the page.

I don't know what is missing out there. I checked another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615318/laravel-5-2-session-not-persisting) but I didn't understand it fully. It seems like quite old as well. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: The `'middleware' => ['web']` in `web.php` is redundant because all Routes in `web.php` already have the web middleware applied, see [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L54).

Comment: @Olivenbaum - Yes I realized this. Thanks.

Comment: Is the request finishing normally or are you using something like `dd()`? If so, try just returning a string right after setting the session value.

Comment: I am not sure but it started to work after a day I posted this question. I am still not sure what the actual problem was.